# Showing a proper inclusion

Tags: real-analysis, notation

Walter Rudin, Principles of Mathematical, Question 2.7b.

> Let $A_1, A_2,...$ be subsets of a metric space. If $B = \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, prove that $\cup_{i=1}^\infty \bar{A_i}\subset \bar{B} $, where $\bar{A}$ is the closure of $A$.

Most of the answer(s) provided online proves only inclusion, not proper inclusion (i.e. $\cup_{i=1}^\infty \bar{A_i}\subseteq \bar{B}$, and not $\cup_{i=1}^\infty \bar{A_i}\subset \bar{B}$). Could anyone explain why proper inclusion in this case follows immediately from inclusion?

Edit: not a duplicate of ([Prove that $\bigcup^{\infty}_{k=1}\overline{A_k} \subset \bar{B}$ if $B=\bigcup^{\infty}_{k=1}A_k $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500381/prove-that-bigcup-infty-k-1-overlinea-k-subset-barb-if-b-bigcup)), but a case of ambiguity with the notation - Rudin uses $\subset$ in place of $\subseteq$ (Thanks Alberto!)

Comment: Rudin uses $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ interchangeably.

Comment: @AlbertoTakase that would explain quite a bit, thanks!

Comment: @AlbertoTakase he does not use $\subseteq$ at all, see page 3 of his book. He even introduces $\in$ as a notation there.

Comment: "Usually a mathematician..." would be a more accurate replacement of "Rudin"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\subset$ just means "subset of" in Rudin, not "proper subset of". He does not use $\subseteq$. See page 3 in chapter 1 where he introduces this notation.

Comment: +1: I spent half an hour to see if Rudin uses $\subseteq$ to no avail.

Comment: @AlbertoTakase some books have an index of notations and many have an introductory chapter like Rudin to settle on notations. Too bad people skip them.

Comment: I looked at books and published papers; he was consistent. It seems $\subseteq$ is modern, but even recently authors (e.g. Munkres) favor $\subset$.